# Every point of a manifold M has a neighborhood homeomorphic to an open subset of $R^n$

Tags: manifolds

"Every point of M has a neighborhood homeomorphic to an open subset of $R^n$."

I would like to understand this definition a bit better. With a homeomorphism, I understand it to be a continuous map with a continuous inverse. But why just continuous why not also differentiable? And why do we map to open subsets of $R^n$, why not map to closed sets?

Comment: How you define differentiable function on abstract space $M$?

Comment: I think one answer to your last question is that topology is defined on open sets by convention.

Answer (score 0):

1. Homeomorphic is enough to have a topological manifold. If, in addition, it is a diffeomorphism, then you've got a smooth manifold. Both are interesting objects themselves.
2. By neighborhood it is actually meant an open neighborhood, so you want (small enough) open subsets of the manifold to look like $\mathbb{R}^n$, since the properties studied are usually local (continuity, differentiability and so on).

Comment: ok, but why open subsets? I don't understand this.

Comment: Local properties are defined in terms of open subsets, in particular, in open balls of $\mathbb{R}^n$. They can usually be defined in closed subsets as well, but that would need some refinement.

Comment: Another good thing about open subsets is that with they are also open submanifolds. For closed subsets you need some extra hypothesis, as you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944321/closed-subset-of-a-manifold-is-a-submanifold-if-there-exists-a-smooth-retract) In general, open sets have more desirable properties in this field.

Comment: Would it be possible to define a set with a differentiable structure (which a Differetiable Manifold is) that is not necessarily locally diffeomorphic to R^n?

Comment: I guess it is possible to define it in a more abstract way, just like you can do the formal derivative of a polynomial without needing the usual topology. But I don't know if that would be as powerful and useful.